# Is there a way to get back the original unsigned document that was sent to DocuSign after it is signed/completed?

Tags: docusignapi

I send the document to DocuSign in draft status. Then, the user (contract owner) logs into DocuSign, adds additional signers and tags, and sends the document for signing.

Is it possible to get the original unsigned document (PDF) sent after the document is completed via the API?

I need the original document to ensure that the user (contract owner) has not changed/modified the document in DocuSign. I want to ensure the signed document is exactly the one I sent via API.
DocuSign does not have granular permissions to block changes to the documents when the Envelope is in draft status.

Answer (score 2):

Re: Is there a way to get back the original unsigned document that was sent to DocuSign after it is signed/completed?

Answer: unfortunately, no. As soon as original documents are uploaded to DocuSign, they are converted into a "flat" (no logic) PDF. The original document is then discarded.

As a workaround, you could programmatically create a template, then create an envelope from the template. Then the user could tag the document without the ability to change the document. See use case 8, creating a template programmatically for code examples. These are on the eg-03 series of examples. Eg, the [PHP code example](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant/blob/master/src/EG008CreateTemplate.php).

Or better, update your application to tag the documents for the user.

We are investigating the idea of enabling the documents in an envelope to be locked. Please ask your DocuSign business or support contact to add your company information to DocuSign internal issue number SMPI-236.